# comparison between two lists. Is it possible to get an output as listed?

Tags: java, jquery, python, shell, comparison

I have two lists (input) Alpha and Beta in two files. [Values are tab separated. Now i am showing it separated with = sign].

```
Alpha:
x=1
y=2
z=3 

Beta:
y=2
a=1
x=1
z=4
```

*I would like to get an output like this:*
**Alpha vs Beta**
|  --  | a=1 |
| z=3  | z=4 |

**Edited** : The program will check first data (x) exists in both or not. If does NOT exists it will list in the output. If exists, it will check value for it is same or not. If value is NOT same, it will list in the output.
ie; 
It will print the output in two cases.
1. If one key (x or y or any) does not exist in both Alpha and Beta.
2. If value of key deosn't match in Alpha or Beta

I have tried with shell script.. but couldnt make it completely !
So it would be better for me if it is shell / python.

But I welcome any language for this :)

Comment: can u explain output how it come frm input list

Comment: ok. i will edit the question.

Comment: Are these inputted from a file that looks like this?

Comment: Yes. Input is from file.

Comment: will there ever be duplicates in the alpha and beta lists, like two y values?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question. No. there wont be any duplicates.

Comment: Then it is map comparison, not list. Please edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the values were tab separated so I made the script work off that. if they are `=` separated, you'll have to change the split. I also skip over any line that won't split on tab with the `try` `except` block. It might not be the most efficient code, but it gets the job done.

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    isBeta = False
    beta = {}
    alpha = {}
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'Beta:':
            isBeta = True
            continue
        elif line.strip() == 'Alpha:' or not line.strip():
            continue


        try:
            k,v = line.split()
        except:
            continue
        if isBeta:
            beta[k] = v
        else:
            alpha[k] =  v

    for k in sorted(set(alpha.keys()+beta.keys())):
        if k not in alpha:
            print '| -- | ' + k + '=' + beta[k] + '|'
        elif k not in beta:
            print '|' + k + '=' + alpha[k] + ' | -- |'
        elif alpha[k] == beta[k]:
            continue
        else:
            print '|' + k + '=' + alpha[k] + ' | ' + k + '=' + beta[k] + '|'
```

Comment: I did it with a shell script too. Thanks for this answer. helped me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

convert lists to map

ie

```
Map<String,String> listToMap(List<String> list){

   Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

   for (String str : list) {
    String[] array= str.split(`=`);
    if (array.length != 2) continue; //ignore invalid line
    map.put(array[0],array[1]);

   }
  return map;
  }
```

then you convert your list to maps

```
Map<String,String> mapA = listToMap(Alpha);
Map<String,String> mapB = listToMap(Beta);
```

create joined keyset,

```
Set<String> keyset = new HashSet<>();
keyset.addAll(mapA.keySet());
keyset.addAll(mapB.keySet());
```

and then only thing what you have left is to compare your lists/maps

```
for (String key : keyset)
{
String valueA = mapA.get(key);
System.out.print(valueA ==null?"---":valueA);
System.out.print(" | ");
String valueB = mapB.get(key);
System.out.print(valueB ==null?"---":valueBA);
System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: Forgot this was open to `Java` as well. Been a while since I've seen it. OOP to the extreme. `System.out.print` :-)

Comment: It's ok Hoopdady. Your script is excellent. I am trying with the real data. I think it's breaking it !!

Comment: @smilyface is it breaking my script?